# Getting crash on JobIntentService onComplete

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, responsys

I am getting following crash reports for Android 8, but I could not find a reason or fix for this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given work is not active: JobWorkItem{id=1 intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.xxx.android cmp=com.xxx.android/com.pushio.manager.PushIOGCMIntentService (has extras) } dcount=1}
at android.app.job.JobParameters.completeWork(JobParameters.java:221)
       at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl$WrapperWorkItem.complete(JobIntentService.java:267)
       at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:393)
       at android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:382)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

I am using PushIO lib for push notifications.

Comment: why Am I getting -1 ?

Comment: I think because of the lack of info what you have tried to fix this. I'm running into the same issue btw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me this happened when I had 2 different `JobIntentService`'s which both used the same JOB_ID (last parameter of `enqueueWork()`

So it looks like this ID needs to be unique throughout your whole app.

Edit: Yes, at first I thought it needed to be unique just for the class you are using it for, but that is not true!
It needs to be unique for your **whole** app, per UID. So if a library you use, uses the same ID, you need to change it to something else. Not sure how you should know which ID's are taken already.

Another thing is, that you can not use different ID's for the same class. It also has to be the same ID for the same class, otherwise a second call with a different JOB ID will be ignored

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will try it today and let you know.

Comment: I am using 1000 as JOB_ID for only one service

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav it is possible that a library is using this ID already, just try a different one

Comment: Found it two different lib using 1000 as JOB_ID for their services :P Thanks

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav how did you find that job id 1000 is already used by other libraries...

Comment: Is there any way to log job ids as I am guessing internal libraries are conflicting.

Comment: this might be help some people who made a mistake of using same integer for their services job id, certainly it is NOT a correct answer. I am 100% using unique JOB_ID (it is 6 value integer) and I still get this error