# App is killed after the IllegalArgumentExeception

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have been working with WorkManager in my app. I am not sure but my app's process gets killed after the below excepion.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given work is not active: JobWorkItem{id=1 intent=Intent {  } dcount=1}
    at android.app.job.JobParameters.completeWork(JobParameters.java:268)
    at androidx.core.app.d$f$a.b(Unknown Source:17)
    at androidx.core.app.d$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at androidx.core.app.d$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have also gone through one of the similar posts : [Getting crash on JobIntentService onComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723024/getting-crash-on-jobintentservice-oncomplete)
And i have made sure that JOB_ID is unique for my JobService.

Another point here is that i am not sure if it is a due to JobService or WorkManager as i am using both in my app.

The workManager version i am using is : 1.0.0-rc01
Please help me to trace down the exact issue.

Comment: WorkManager doesn't use `JobIntentService` or `AsyncTask` at all. Why do you think this is related to WorkManager?